# Relationships many-to-many - Automatic Initialization

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

The problem concerns the lack of linkage relationships entries with 2 tables.

I created two classes:

File:

```
public class File
{
public int FileId {get; set;}
public string Name{get; set;{
public ICollection<int> TagId {get; set;}
public virtual ICollection<Tag> Tag {get; set;}
}
```

Tag:

```
public class Tag
{
public int TagId {get; set;}
public string Name {get; set;}
public ICollection<int> FileId {get; set;}
public ICollection<File> File {get; set;}
}
```

Creating tables:

```
public DbSet<File> Files { get; set; }
public DbSet<Tag> Tags{ get; set; }
```

In the database automaicly created a further table TagFiles, in which there are relationships between tables.

I added the StartInitializer class which initiates me to the database each time anew. Inside an init method I add new records:

```
...
var tags = new List<Tag>
{
new Tag() { TagId = 1, Name = "A"},
new Tag() { TagId = 2, Name = "B"},
new Tag() { TagId = 3, Name = "C"},
new Tag() { TagId = 4, Name = "D"},
new Tag() { TagId = 5, Name = "E"},
new Tag() { TagId = 6, Name = "F"},
new Tag() { TagId = 7, Name = "G"}
};
tags.ForEach(g => context.Tags.Add(g));
context.SaveChanges();

var files = new List<File>
{
new File() { FileId = 1,  Name = "1", TagId = new List<int>{1, 3, 2, 4}}
};
files.ForEach(g => context.Files.Add(g));
context.SaveChanges();
...
```

Unfortunately FileETag table entries are not added automatically, although it seems to me that `TagId = new List <int> {1, 3, 2, 4}` should be ensured. Something is missing here?

Comment: Can you explain better those `public ICollection<int>`?

Comment: I think those `public ICollection<int> FileId {get; set;}` `public ICollection<int> FileId {get; set;}` are unneeded. instead above `public virtual ICollection<Tag> Tag {get; set;}` add `[InverseProperty("File")]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is with your unneeded collection of in id's.

when you use EF - code first inorder to get many to many relation table you have to explicitly mention it. other-wise it will be considered as 2 one to many relations.

this is the changes I suggest:

```
public class File
{
    public int FileId {get; set;}
    public string Name{get; set;}
    [InverseProperty("Files")]
    public virtual ICollection<Tag> Tags {get; set;}
}

public class Tag
{
   public int TagId {get; set;}
   public string Name {get; set;}
   public ICollection<File> Files {get; set;}
}
```

notice the `[InverseProperty("Files")]` which creates that connection.

Comment: And now how to combine tags with the files if I don't have of field ICollection <int> Tags in model?

Comment: this is exactly what `[InverseProperty("Files")]` is doing for you, it saying in the class `tag` there is a list named `"Files"` that are linked to my tags